# How to get the list from a node and use that list in a recyclerView to get data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a  app with chatrooms where I want to show the people in that chatroom.When someone joins the chatroom I set the value of their node to be true.Like this

[image]

Like you can see I also have the data of users underit.I want to use the list of members/documentid and use that list to get the data of only those people from the profiledata node.

**My class**

```
public class chatroommembers extends AppCompatActivity {

   String documentid;
   RecyclerView recyclerView;
   DatabaseReference peopleref;
   DatabaseReference membersref;
   private List<User> list;
   private MembersAdapter membersAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatroommembers);

        Intent data = getIntent();
        documentid = data.getStringExtra("documentid");
        peopleref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("profiledata");
        membersref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chatrooms").child("members").child(documentid);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.membersRecycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        list = new ArrayList<>();


        membersref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
for (DataSnapshot snapshot1:snapshot.getChildren()){
    String uid = snapshot1.getKey();
    DatabaseReference peoplesref = peopleref.child(uid);
}

membersAdapter = new MembersAdapter(list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(membersAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }

    public static class User{
        String fullname,imageUrl,Uid,Email,Buddies;

        public String getFullname() {
            return fullname;
        }
        public User(){

        }

        public void setFullname(String fullname) {
            this.fullname = fullname;
        }

        public String getImageUrl() {
            return imageUrl;
        }

        public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }

        public String getUid() {
            return Uid;
        }

        public void setUid(String uid) {
            Uid = uid;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return Email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            Email = email;
        }

        public String getBuddies() {
            return Buddies;
        }

        public void setBuddies(String buddies) {
            Buddies = buddies;
        }

        public User(String fullname, String imageUrl, String uid, String email, String buddies) {
            this.fullname = fullname;
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            Uid = uid;
            Email = email;
            Buddies = buddies;
        }
    }

    public class MembersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MembersAdapter.MembersViewHolder>{

        private List<User> list;

        public MembersAdapter(List<User> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MembersAdapter.MembersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_recycler_layout,parent,false);
            return new MembersAdapter.MembersViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MembersAdapter.MembersViewHolder holder, int position) {
            User ld = list.get(position);
            holder.name.setText(ld.getFullname());
            if (ld.getImageUrl().equals("noimage")){
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.profile).into(holder.circleImageView);
            }else{
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(ld.getImageUrl()).into(holder.circleImageView);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public class MembersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            TextView name;
            CircleImageView circleImageView;

            public MembersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usersname);
                circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usersimage);
            }
        }

    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a fairly standard operation known as a client-side join. In Android it'd look something like this:

```
String chatroomId = "-MBISFO12u2tok9CeWwi";
DatabaseReference membersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatrooms/members").child(chatroomId);
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/profiledata")
membersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot memberSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uid = memberSnapshot.getKey();
            
            DatabaseReference userRef = usersRef.child(uid);
            
            userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot userSnapshot) {
                    Log.i("USER", userSnapshot.child("Full name").getValue(String.class));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            });
            
            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```